# What is the best way to read a file in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I am writing a JAVA program to simulate assembler (as an assignment in my college).

I have an assembly program which is given as an input to this assembler.

The general format of every statement in assembly code is as follows:

`[Label] OPCODE OPERAND1 [OPERAND2]` (each term separated by a space)

`Label` and `OPERAND2` are optional parts so in some statements these may be unavailable.

In my java code I read each line and then use `StringTokenizer` to get the 4 parts separated by spaces.

My question is whenever `Label` AND/OR `OPERAND2` are not available how can I find out that the first values returned by `StringTokenizer` is actually `OPCODE` value and similarly second value is OPERAND1 value? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does a label always end in a colon?

Comment: No! That is the big problem!! I have given it a thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

1. a `Label` can never be an `OPCODE`,
2. and depending how many `OPCODE` values exist,

you might just create a method `isOpcode(String s)` and test the first part after Tokenizing. If it passes, `Label` must have been missing. If it fails, `Label` must exist.

Depending on the results of that test, you can count the remaining parts to determine if `OPERAND2` is present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but this is not efficient, is it?

Comment: It is efficient, NullPointer. At least, I don't see how you make it much more efficient.

Comment: There is some cost to string comparisons, and also depends on the number of available `OPCODE` values. Even if there were a pattern to the `OPCODE`s or the line in general, Regular Expressions are not often known for speed (but are extremely useful sometimes). There would be ways to optimize this, or any other check to handle the assembly statement, but don't over-optimize before the problem is solved! Learn **and understand** your assignment, then make it faster : )

Answer (score 0):

Parse the line and put it in an ArrayList. 
If ArrayList.size() is 4 than you have all the 4.
If it is 3 than test ArrayList.get(0) if it is an Op than the label is unavailable,if it is not than than operand 2 is unavailable.
If size is 2 than both label and operand 2 are unavailable.
I suggest you make a class for each format(I format,R format...)